# Can GLSL macro expansion do this?

Tags: opengl, macros, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

Consider the following GLSL functions:

```
float Pow3 (const in float f) {
    return f * f * f;
}

float Pow4 (const in float f) {
    return f * f * f * f;
}

float Pow5 (const in float f) {
    return f * f * f * f * f;
}
```

... and so on. Is there a way to **#define** a GLSL macro that can generate *n* multiplications-of-*f*-by-itself at compile time, not using the built-in GLSL **pow()** function of course?

Comment: Why are you "of course" not using the builtin `pow()` function?

Comment: standard, builtin functions - like 'pow' - are optimized and should be a little faster that the custom version.

Comment: This was an example for my question, it's not about the pow(). Should have used "f / f / f / f" instead I guess...

Comment: Hi fen, are you saying pow(5, 4) is bound to be more optimized than 5 * 5 * 5 * 5? Not really worried about my pow() calls per se -- again, what if I want to divide without a loop. Or do something more intricate. As mentioned, this was a general-purpose "can the GLSL macro system write out an arithmetic operation with n operands" question about the general capabilities of GLSL macros (and if-can, then-how). That being said, in a full-screen-quad shader required to process 2 million fragments >60x per second with numerous calculations, every tiny optimization difference counts, it all adds up.

Comment: [Recursive macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447557/can-we-have-recursive-macros) can do this, if GLSL supports them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GLSL preprocessor "equals" to the standard C preprocessor. Indeed, you can reach what you want with the following preprocessor definition:

```
#define POW(a, b) Pow ## b ## (a)
```

But pay attention, since the concatenation operator (`##`) is available only starting from GLSL 1.30. Indeed using previous GLSL versions this macro will generate a compiler error.

Still wondering why you don't use the `pow` function...

Comment: Thanks! As  mentioned above, this was an example for my question, it's not about the pow(). Should have used "f / f / f / f" instead for instance. Now, I don't see the * operator at all in the above macro. It's named POW and ... calls "Pow"? Or is this a built-in macro-language "function"?

Comment: Oh I get it. If I gave b=4 and a=5 it would expand into a call Pow4(5). Neat but I'd still have to define Pow4 manually, right? This is what I want to avoid -- looking for a way to have the macro system write out 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 for POW(5, 4). Again, as an example, it's not about the pow() by itself :)

Comment: If it is so, you're out of luck. Write these operator sequences using a loop: normally these kind of loop are unrolled by the compiler.

Comment: OK, at least good to know it *can't* be done that way. Unrollable-loop in a custom function PowN(n, val) it is, then.

Comment: I think `#define POW(a,b) ({ int c; float t=a; for(c=1;c<b;c++)t*=a; t;})` may work as well, and no defines needed. I haven't tested it, though. It requires that a block returns a value (which is true in c, on which glsl is based). So it can be done. Note that the loop is unrolled anyway, so it's functionally equal to a recursive tail-call-optimized function or a recursively expanded macro. Note that the define contains a block and that c is local to this block. The last statement returns the value of the block. Again, I haven't tested it.

Comment: "equals the standard C preprocessor" is not true. Otherwise it would actually be possible to do it with variadic macro expansion, which is in c but not in glsl. At least not in all implementations.

Comment: @johannes_lalala can you see the double quotes on equals? They mean exactly what you said.

Comment: Sorry man, no front. But double quoted equals is not defined. We cannot know what you mean with "equals".. If you mean 'equals except variadic macro expansion' then please write that. I was mislead by the answer into thinking that `__VA_ARGS__` actually was possible.