# stringify arbitrary number of variables

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

For a single variable (or a given number of variables), it's easy to use macros to stringify variables. E.g. for 2 variables, I can do:

```
#define STRINGIFY(var1, var2) (std::string(#var1) + " " + #var2)
```

Is there a way to extend the above with either variadic macros or some other sort of compile-time trickery, to ultimately get a `STRINGIFY` function that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments?

Comment: I think the answer is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132017/how-do-i-write-a-recursive-for-loop-repeat-macro-to-generate-c-code-with-the-c). Looks pretty tedious doing that straight forward.

Comment: Why resort to macro?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  wish I understood what's going on in that question

Comment: @NickyC I'd be perfectly happy with a non-macro solution, I just don't know of any

Comment: @NickyC Stringifying is one of the rare features where you actually need the c-preprocessor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK, I missed that.

Comment: @eddi I thought [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17147941/1413395) might be a good lead. IIRC there might be also some boost stuff helpful for realizing such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood what you're trying to do. The code below tokenizes, at compile time, `__VA_ARGS__`. It does not check the syntax: it blindly replaces the white-space and commas with `'\0'`, stores the start of identifiers in `arg` and the number of arguments in `argc`.

```
#include <iostream>

template < unsigned N > constexpr
unsigned countarg( const char( &s )[N], unsigned i = 0, unsigned c = 0 )
{
  return
    s[i] == '\0'
    ? i == 0
    ? 0
    : c + 1
    : s[i] == ','
    ? countarg( s, i + 1, c + 1 )
    : countarg( s, i + 1, c );
}

template < unsigned N > constexpr
unsigned skipid( char( &s )[N], unsigned i = 0 )
{
  return s[i] == '\0' || s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t' || s[i] == ','
    ? i
    : skipid( s, i + 1 );
}

template < unsigned N, unsigned M > constexpr
unsigned tokenize( char( &s )[N], const char*(&a)[M], unsigned i = 0, unsigned j = 0 )
{
  return s[i] == '\0'
    ? i
    : s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t' || s[i] == ','
    ? ((s[i] = '\0'),
      tokenize( s, a, ++i, j ))
    : ((a[j] = s + i),
      i = skipid( s, i ),
      tokenize( s, a, i, ++j ));
}

#define TOKENIZEVA( ... ) char orig[] = #__VA_ARGS__; const unsigned argc = countarg(#__VA_ARGS__); const char* arg[argc]; tokenize( orig, arg );

#define PRINT( ... ) { TOKENIZEVA(__VA_ARGS__) for ( auto s : arg ) std::cout << s << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  PRINT( first, second, third, fourth );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't recurse in CPP, but you can `#define` a lot of macros (`DO1`, `DO2` .. `DO128`) and then use one "generic" Macro that expands to the macro with the appropriate suffix.

[P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) is one lib (a header file actually) that provides the boilerplate to do this. [`P99_SER`](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__for_gaa8397413f3ecf6c5f24463a728989ab4.html#gaa8397413f3ecf6c5f24463a728989ab4) pastes arguments delimited with spaces after calling `P99_STRINGIFY` on each of them.

```
#include "p99_for.h"
P99_SER(P99_STRINGIFY, first,second,third,fourth,fifth,6)
```

expands to

```
$ gcc -E test.c | tail -n 1
    "first" "second" "third" "fourth" "fifth" "6"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following (up to hard coded 6 arguments):

```
#define NARGS_(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5 , _6, N, ...) N
#define NARGS(args...) NARGS_(args..., 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define CAT_(a, b) a ## b
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_(a, b)

#define name_1(x)                     #x
#define name_2(x, x2)                 #x , #x2
#define name_3(x, x2, x3)             #x , #x2, #x3
#define name_4(x, x2, x3, x4)         #x , #x2, #x3, #x4
#define name_5(x, x2, x3, x4, x5)     #x , #x2, #x3, #x4, #x5
#define name_6(x, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6) #x , #x2, #x3, #x4, #x5, #x6

#define names(args...) CAT(name_, NARGS(args))(args)
```

So `names(var1, var2)` results in `"var1", "var2"`. (That you can pass to any function).
You can also customize `name_x`.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e3ce0012ecc00b3)

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for having an *arbitrary* number of arguments, not capped by some upper limit of my laziness/code mess I'm willing to tolerate

Comment: that said, if you have a way of doing what you did by having `O(log(N))` lines of code for a cap of `N` variables - I'd find that acceptable

Answer (score 1):

*Stringify [an] arbitrary number of variables?*

is one question and:

*Way to ... get a STRINGIFY function that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments?*

is another question. Guessing that the *first* question is the one that matters
to you, this is enough:

```
#define STRINGIFY(tokz) (std::string(#tokz))
```

Some nonsense usage:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#define STRINGIFY(tokz) (std::string(#tokz))

#define FOO(x,y) \
    {   int x = 1 ; int y = 2 ; std::string s = STRINGIFY(x y); \
        cout << '[' << s  << ']' << " -> " << x << ' ' << y  << '\n'; \
    }
#define BAR(x,y,z) \
    {   char x = 'x'; char y = 'y'; char z = 'z'; \
        std::string s = STRINGIFY([ x y z ]); \
        cout << s << " -> " << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n'; \
    } 

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << STRINGIFY(p q) << '\n' << STRINGIFY(r s t) << '\n';
    FOO(a,b);
    BAR(c,d,e);
    return 0;
}
```

Preprocessed prettily:

```
$  g++ -E main.cpp | astyle 
...
...
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << (std::string("p q")) << '\n' << (std::string("r s t")) << '\n';
    {
        int a = 1 ;
        int b = 2 ;
        std::string s = (std::string("a b"));
        cout << '[' << s << ']' << " -> " << a << ' ' << b << '\n';
    };
    {
        char c = 'x';
        char d = 'y';
        char e = 'z';
        std::string s = (std::string("[ c d e ]"));
        cout << s << " -> " << c << ' ' << d << ' ' << e << '\n';
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
$ g++ main.cpp && ./a.out
p q
r s t
[a b] -> 1 2
[ c d e ] -> x y z
```

Comment: won't compile as is, one must use STRINGIFY(p q).c_str() since the operator << has no built-in overload with a std::string param

Comment: @hymced Please see [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)
and [this demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e09349bbdaa05c4) and [that demo](https://godbolt.org/g/hcJYMK)

Comment: very interesting, I wasn't aware of those online compilers! so thanks ;) It appears that in VC++ I must explicitly #include <string>, whereas gcc won't need it...

Answer (score 0):

Alas, you can't do recursion in the preprocessor, but you can kinda-sorta make a "apply macro to all arguments to this variadic macro" macro.

A useful idea is that when calling a function-style macro, the () can be part of the *argument*. This allows you to do some funky things. In your specific example...

First, a macro that tells us how many arguments are in a `__VA_ARGS__` pack:

```
#define NUM_ARGS_(_10, _9, _8, _7, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1, N, ...) N
#define NUM_ARGS(...) NUM_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

Next, a macro that applies a given macro to every element of a `__VA_ARGS__` pack independently:

```
#define FOREACH(MACRO, ...) FOREACH_(NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), MACRO, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_(N, M, ...) FOREACH__(N, M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH__(N, M, ...) FOREACH_##N(M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_1(M, A) M(A)
#define FOREACH_2(M, A, ...) M(A)  FOREACH_1(M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_3(M, A, ...) M(A) FOREACH_2(M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_4(M, A, ...) M(A) FOREACH_3(M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_5(M, A, ...) M(A) FOREACH_4(M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_6(M, A, ...) M(A) FOREACH_5(M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_7(M, A, ...) M(A) FOREACH_6(M, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOREACH_8(M, A, ...) M(A) FOREACH_7(M, __VA_ARGS__)
// Extend in the obvious way for as many iterations as needed.
```

A simple "stringify one thing" macro (that makes sure its argument expands):

```
#define STRINGIFY_(X) #X
#define STRINGIFY(X) STRINGIFY_(X)
```

And now let's put all the pieces together to make a nice example that builds a string array:

```
#define STRINGIFY_ALL(...) FOREACH(STRINGIFY, __VA_ARGS__)

#define COMMA(X) X,
#define COMMA_STRINGIFY(X) COMMA(STRINGIFY(X))

#define STRING_LITERAL_ARRAY(...) const char* STUFF[ NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__) ] = { FOREACH(COMMA_STRINGIFY, __VA_ARGS__) };

STRING_LITERAL_ARRAY(I, AM, A, POTATO);

// Will yield:
const char* STUFF[ 4 ] { "I", "AM", "A", "POTATO" };
```

Hopefully you can see how you can write different "lambda-like" macros to use with FOREACH to do all sorts of exciting things.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but doesn't work in the 0 argument case. You end up with "", instead of nothing.

Answer (score -2):

Try `__VA_ARGS__` macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRINGIFY(...) #__VA_ARGS__

int main()
{
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int varN;

    printf(STRINGIFY(var1 var2 varN)); // or STRINGIFY(var1, var2, varN)

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
var1 var2 varN
```

Comment: That's not the same as concatenating the plain arguments to get a symbol.

Comment: You did not separate the arguments with commas. And even if you did, `__VA_ARGS__` does not process comma, therefore what you will get is a string made of arguments separated by commas. `__VA_ARGS__` is almost an exact copy of the tail arguments.