# Is it possible to achieve infinite compilation time in C (i.e. without templates)?

Tags: c, compilation

So, the title. It is generally known that it is possible to write C++ program, which would require infinite time to compile (in theory). But is it possible to write such program in plain C? Or is there a way to slow down compilation time to at least several minutes with a small program?

Comment: Are you allowed to use preprocessor macros?  If so, you could easily use them to expand the code exponentially.

Comment: have a look on this questions about recursive macros in C/C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447557/can-we-have-recursive-macros

Comment: @JS1 There are no limitations on C features. I'd wanted to make it work for gcc. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: While recursive macros could get infinite *preprocessing* time, the C compiler itself will never see the generated code unless the preprocessor finally turns it loose, so I'm not sure if that will fit the bill of your requirements.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is your concrete point? Perhaps edit your question to improve it. What is your metric of "small program" (do you include or not the preprocessing)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I was wondering about the possibility of DoS attack on server during some programming contest. It came to my mind when I was writing simplified version of this server as an assignment.

Comment: But that is easy to counter: just set a limit (using [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)...) on the compilation server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example you asked for, with exponentially increasing macros.

```
#define FOO  i++  // Substitute any statement here for i++
#define FOO1 FOO ; FOO
#define FOO2 FOO1 ; FOO1
#define FOO3 FOO2 ; FOO2
#define FOO4 FOO3 ; FOO3
#define FOO5 FOO4 ; FOO4
#define FOO6 FOO5 ; FOO5
// Keep going however much you want
...
#define FOO40 FOO39 ; FOO39

volatile int i;

int main(void)
{
    FOO40;  // This expands to 2^40 statements.
}
```

I used `FOO18` for a timing test to see what would happen.  I tested both the preprocessor time and the compilation time separately:

```
(Preprocessor phase)
time gcc -E foo.c -o foo.i
1.7 seconds

(Compilation phase)
time gcc foo.i -o foo
21 seconds
```

Out of curiosity I kept trying bigger and bigger values.  Unfortunately, at some point the compiler ran out of memory (the preprocessor was fine).  I got this error:

> cc1: out of memory allocating 16842751 bytes after a total of 403505152 bytes

At `FOO16` with `-O2`, I was able to get 2:23 compilation time without running out of memory.  So if you want to get an even longer compilation time, first find out many many statements you can put into a single function without running out of memory (`FOO16` for me).  Then make several functions, like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    FOO16;
}

void bar1(void)
{
    FOO16;
}

void bar2(void)
{
    FOO16;
}

// etc...
```

Comment: Stricto sensu, it is not "infinite compilation", but "a huge amount of time needed for compilation in preprocessing phase".

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch See my edit.  I timed both phases separately, and most of the time was spent compiling, not preprocessing.

Comment: @JS1 Thanks, that looks great. As a followup question, is there any way to make it consume only time, but not memory?

Comment: @vaeea See my recent edit.  The amount of memory seems to be based on the largest function you create.  So you can pick a `FOO` size that fits within memory, and then simply create multiple functions all using that same `FOO` macro.  The amount of memory should stay roughly the same, but the amount of time will increase linearly with the number of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Experimentally, if you ask a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) to compile *with [optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)* some C code containing a single (or very few) C function(s) with many thousands of statements, the compilation time is growing a lot.

By *experience*, **compilation with `gcc -O2` of a single function** with many thousand C statements **requires a time proportional to the *square* of the number of statements** (more exactly number of [Gimple](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) statements after preprocessing & gimplification).

The intuition explaining that is that the algorithms for register allocation, instruction scheduling, and middle-end optimizations are often worse than *O(n)* ; naive non-optimizing C compilers like [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git), [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/), `8cc` etc don't have such time behavior (but generate code really worse than `gcc -O2`...)

BTW, you could play (on Linux) with my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) program (which generates some more or less random C code, then compile it and `dlopen` it, to show that you can `dlopen` many hundred thousands of shared objects). Read its source code, it will illustrate my point.

More seriously, I did (in the past) experiment the same issue in old versions of [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), which generates C++ code suitable for extension of GCC. I had to split in several routines some huge sequential initialization code.

You might compile with `gcc -ftime-report -O2` such a huge function to understand more precisely in which optimization passes is the compiler spending its time.

At last, if you want a small source code, you can cheat by asking it to `#include "some-huge-file.c"` but I believe that does not count.

Comment: Thank you, that's really interesting. I didn't mention that in my question, but my intent was to use as little additional tools as possible and to write minimal code.

Answer (score 1):

### Include recursively

```
#include __FILE__
```

Most compilers will probably bail out early, but theoretically, this would cause infinite compilation.

### Include (or compile directly, or link against) a device instead of a file

```
#include "/dev/tty"
```

On systems that support it, this causes the compiler to wait for input. Similarly, you could use a named pipe.

### Find a bug in the compiler

It is possible the compiler has a logic error that will cause it to loop forever.