# Macro to Replace For Loop

Tags: c, header, macros, c-preprocessor

Consider the macro below. How can I unroll the for loops using macros and export lots of macros cleanly into a readable header?

**macro.h**

```
#define ARR(n) \
typedef int arr##n[n]; \
void arr##n##_add(arr##n res, arr##n x, arr##n y){ \
    int i = 0; \
    for (; i < n; i++) { \
        res[i] = x[i] + y[i]; \
    } \
}

ARR(3)
ARR(4)
```

Running this through the pre-processor with `gcc -E -P macro.h > out.h` we get:

**out.h**

```
typedef int arr3[3]; 

void arr3_add(arr3 res, arr3 x, arr3 y){ 
    int i = 0; 
    for (; i < 3; i++) { 
        res[i] = x[i] + y[i]; 
    } 
}

typedef int arr4[4]; 

void arr4_add(arr4 res, arr4 x, arr4 y){ 
    int i = 0; 
    for (; i < 4; i++) { 
        res[i] = x[i] + y[i]; 
    } 
}
```

Using [token pasting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) like above we avoid having to repeat definitions. Now there are two things I would like to know:

1. How can each `for(;i; i < n)` be replaced (unrolled) with e.g:

   ```
   res[0] = x[0] + y[0];
   res[1] = x[1] + y[1];
   ...
   res[n] = x[n] + y[n];
   ```
2. What is a clean way of exporting lots of macro hackery into a readable header? Should I create a shell function inside my `make` file exports the final header to an `include` directory?

Maybe there are better ways of doing this. Any alternatives welcome.

Comment: 'Clean way' and 'macro hackery' are pretty much mutually exclusive terms.

Comment: What is the problem with functions and readable code?

Comment: Are you sure this is at all beneficial?  Why would you want such specialized functions and types, rather than simply taking the dimension as an argument to the functions?

Comment: Even if this not the best way as part of my C education knowing this would be helpful. So granted that this may not be "beneficial" or "clean" how do we do it?

Comment: You should probably look at [Boost::Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/), which can be used with C as well as C++.  Not that it is going to make the code readable, but (I believe) it will allow you to unwrap your loops.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It would be better to not introduce dependencies unnecessarily unless it would be too much work to do ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution that is referred to by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447557/can-we-have-recursive-macros/12540675#12540675) using [these macro functions](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms):

```
#define ARR(n, m) \
static inline void vec##n##_add(vec##n res, \
        vec##n const u, vec##n const v) { \
        m }

#define ADD(i, n) res[i] = u[i] + v[i]; 
ARR(3, EVAL(REPEAT(3, ADD, ~)))
ARR(4, EVAL(REPEAT(4, ADD, ~)))
```

Which does as asked but in a convoluted, hacky, ugly way... In particular, the use of recursive macros for what should be an iterative operation.