# Looping with macros

Tags: c++, macros

I need to do a loop where I turn this simple example of reflection:

```
std::string mystring[3] = {{"mystring[0]"},{"mystring[1]"},{"mystring[2]"}};
```

into a more managable form for longer arrays.  The solution sounds like I should either use macros with a loop, or recursion. However, macros don't support loops or recursion!

How do I create a macro to handle this for me arbitrarily?

```
#define NAME_OBJ(type, name, size)
```

Comment: Avoid macros whenever possible. Use proper functions when you can.

Comment: what you want? what's wrong with a function return a vector<string>?

Comment: How is it an " example of reflection"?

Comment: After a ton of searching, I mostly wrote this question using the Q&A format of stack overflow so that I can find the answer again later.  Yeah, I know that macros should be avoided where possible, but they are essential when it comes to reflection.  This is simple code, but in reality, std::string is actually a structure with reflection around it which requires the literal name of the instance.

Comment: @Stewart I'm currious as to why would consider `std::string` to be using "reflection" since C++ does not have that feature..? And where do macros come in as regards to "reflection"?

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the word wrong, but I don't think so.  "Reflection" is the concept of bringing in run-time-type-information.  std::string itself isn't reflection, but you can embed meta-information about your object in it.  You're right that the language doesn't support it, but we can use the pre-processor to get around that... Take this macro: `#define STRUCT(name, body) struct name { std::string m_body; body  name() : m_body(#body){} };`.  This struct will use the second argument as a C++ body, and will also save it to a string in the member, allowing you to parse it during runtime.

Comment: That's a super-simple example, but you can imagine how you can start embedding sizes and type names as well.  BOOST_HANA uses macros in this way quite a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Boost. If it fails, try using more Boost.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repeat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/comma_if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>

#define DETAIL_NAME_OBJ_ELEM(z, n, name) \
    BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n) { BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name) "[" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(n) "]" }

#define NAME_OBJ(type, name, size) \
    type name[size] = { BOOST_PP_REPEAT(size, DETAIL_NAME_OBJ_ELEM, name) }
```

Then this:

```
NAME_OBJ(std::string, mystring, 3);
```

... expands to this:

```
std::string mystring[3] = {
    { "mystring" "[" "0" "]" },
    { "mystring" "[" "1" "]" },
    { "mystring" "[" "2" "]" }
};
```

... in which the adjacent string literals are then automatically merged before compilation.

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81d4b3a05a9b9e61)

Comment: Worth noting that "using more boost" is likely to severely hurt your compile times. The boost headers are notorious for dragging in a shit ton of other boost headers and other crap (even when they don't really need to and could just include something more specific). I've shaved *minutes* off of a real-life projects compile time by simply a) replace boost headers with std equivalents and b) remove unneeded boost header includes and/or include more targeted boost includes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl fair warning, although it does depend a lot on what Boost library we're talking about. But this is more of an humorous placeholder instead of "here, you can do this" ;)

Comment: @Quentin Indeed. Not all boost libraries are created equal. Just thought I'd mention it since it has bitten me severely in the past.

Comment: Quick question:  What's the advantage of `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name)` over `#name`?

Comment: @Stewart `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE` ensures that substitution happens before stringification (otherwise you stringize the name of the macro that was passed in). It might not be needed here, but since `name` comes through the pipes of `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` I prefer to be safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on a great answer to handling macros here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540675/1723954

I modified/simplified the solution for this specific case:

```
#define NAME_OBJ(type, name, size) \
    type name[size] = { INIT_ELEMENT_ ## size(name) }

#define INIT_ELEMENT_1(name) { #name "[0]" }
#define INIT_ELEMENT_2(name) INIT_ELEMENT_1(name), { #name "[1]" }
#define INIT_ELEMENT_3(name) INIT_ELEMENT_2(name), { #name "[2]" }
...
```

The solution does not allow for very-very-very large arrays, only as large as you are willing to code.  I did 128 and that's fine for all of the cases in my project.

Comment: You have a little mistake at `#define INIT_ELEMENT_3(name) INIT_ELEMENT_3(name), { #name "[2]" }`, must be `#define INIT_ELEMENT_3(name) INIT_ELEMENT_2(name), { #name "[2]" }`

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, macros in C++ do not support loops or recursion, such that you would have to duplicate lines of code.

A common way of solving such topics is to write a program - let's say `myGenerator`,  which contains a "normal" C++-loop and which's output is a C++ source file (.cpp or .h). Integrate then a call to `myGenerartor` in a build step before building the rest of your program.