# python "print" like function in c

Tags: c, printf

I am new to C and I use to code in python, and I usually print too much variables and text to test my code and printf statement is irritating sometimes. I want to write a function in c which works exactly like print function in python.

**I am facing two problem while writing the function.**

1. I want to take n number of arguments as input to the function.
2. I want to take any data type as input to the function,
   for Eg: `print(12); print("hello"); print(123.12)` should not raise error.

**What have I done so Far**

3. I found solution for taking n number of arguments using <stdarg.h>, but I have to specify the data type of the first argument which is not what I want.
4. "generic selection" Macros can be used to call different function on different data type of argument passed but not sure how it can be done, [here](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/2784/generic-selection-based-on-multiple-arguments) is the link which I used for reference.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Python and C are *very* different programming languages. You should read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), then the documentation of your C compiler and debugger. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) be sure to compile with all warnings and debug info : `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source C software, like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: In python, the runtime has information about the type of the objects passed to the function.  In C, that is not the case.  IOW, you cannot easily do what you are trying.

Comment: You _could_ have done something like this with `_Generic` and recursive macros, but C doesn't have recursive macros... You can [hack around that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447557/can-we-have-recursive-macros), but it looks pretty complicated

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just use `printf`?

Comment: I am learning C and it's best to learn using real life problems. I am not building any program. @mkrieger1

Comment: If you want to code in C, then code in C. If you want to use those features you want, then use Python instead.

Comment: What you want to do might be fun, but it's not how you code C. And this is essentially completely impossible. It cannot be done. At least not in a nice way. So continue if you find it as a fun exercise, but if it is just to avoid format strings in `printf` then rethink.

Comment: @klutt yeah it's more like learning experience to me, it raises my interest if I do stuff like this while learning.

Comment: @wetler I'd suggest learning the basics first. What you want to do (which is impossible, but might work with some workarounds) requires good knowledge about the language.

Comment: But the best you can do is probably stuff like `int print_int(int x) { return printf("%d", x); }` but it's not really worth the effort

Comment: Start learning c++ instead

Answer (score 5):

> I want to write a function in c which works exactly like print function in python.

**You simply cannot do that** (because of [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) : at runtime, type information is lost in C). Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

In practice, you'll better write one function per datatype in C to print it. So it would be `void print_int(int);` to print an integer, `void print_double(double);` to print a double, etc. Once you have a collection of such functions you might use [`_Generic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) inside a macro (but that is rarely useful; it can handle a finite set of types).

Study for inspiration the source code of existing open source C software on [github](https://githjub.com/) or elsewhere. Look for inspiration inside the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/), [GTK](https://gtk.org/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (and perhaps *inside* the source code of [Python](https://python.org/); half of the Python interpreter is coded in C)

Read also the documentation of your C compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/). So compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

Perhaps you want to implement some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) abstract data type in C. Then take inspiration from [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or the runtime of [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) and dive inside their source code.

Once you are more familiar with C, read some C draft standard, e.g. [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf)

Consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Consider also sometimes *generating* some C code, like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) does.

Budget weeks of work.

Comment: looks like too much work for a simple print function.

Comment: Your simple print function cannot exist (it is "infinitely complex" since impossible), so indeed you'll need weeks of work to understand why. If you cannot afford that work, give up the idea of learning C.

Comment: I will try to write the function but it looks like it is impossible for me right now, but I will come back to it, when I can.

Comment: Spend more time in learning C, instead of trying to write a function which cannot exist

Comment: Rather  change language to C++

Comment: @P__J: C++ is really difficult to learn