# Is it possible to calculate Fibonacci sequence by preprocessor directives in C?

Tags: c, macros, fibonacci

Just for personal study and better understanding of C code preprocessor :

I am wondering if it is possible to implement **Fibonacci** function by **preprocessor directives** in C language.

Normal definition of Fibonacci function could be:

```
int f(int i) {  // i should be non-negative integer
    if (i <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return f(i - 1) + f(i - 2);
}
```

The approach of using the template metaprogramming technique in C++ is not what I need.

---

It seems that it is not possible to perform recursive calculations by using the code preprocessor?

Comment: Why do you want to do it with a macro?

Comment: You don't need the `if ... else` construct to generate a Fibonacci sequence. You start with two predefined values.

Comment: In practice, Fibionacci grows very quickly. You want some [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and you should use some [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library such as [GMPlibb](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: A 64-bit integer can store up to the 94th term.

Comment: Please explain -in more than one paragraph of written English- why you need to use macros and what for. Refer to [this C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: General advice. Don't use macros when you can use a function.

Comment: I suppose this is for fun. [This code](https://gist.github.com/DavidBuchanan314/b9230fe7d335a1caf90483dbb00a5375) implements a Mandelbrot calculation using only the preprocessor, pretty fun stuff BTW.

Comment: The most relevant question, already asked, but deserving of underlining, is why use macros? Also if you want C, present C style code not python, it would take you 30 seconds `return (i <= 1) ? 1 : fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2);`

Comment: From a time complexity point of view, recursion surely must be about the worst possible way to calculate the Fibonacci sequence, being O(exp(n)).

Comment: @klutt: OP does not say they want to implement the Fibonacci function with a macro. They ask whether it is possible, which indicates only that they want to know, not that they want to do it. Often understanding the capabilities of various tools is useful for understanding them, learning more, inspiring creativity, and knowing what is available in future situations. And they ask whether it is possible with preprocessor directives, not with macros alone.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I totally agree. However, before OP edited it, the question looked quite different.

Comment: I'm so sorry, it's really my problem. Thank you very much for your help~ @klutt

Comment: I posted the question but then I discovered my inadequate expression, so I edited many times. I think I need more thinking before asking. Thank you~ @EricPostpischil

Comment: @BinChen That's not a big problem. I just asked because the reason why you wonder can greatly impact how a proper answer would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think macro in C can support recursive macro. But Fibonacci is possible macro.
By using the fomular of nth number

`#define Fibonacci(n) (POW(1+POW(5,1/2),n) - POW(1-POW(5,1/2),n))/POW(5,1/2)`

Comment: Well, you would need to define `POW`, and be careful that `1/2` doesn't get evaluated as `0`.

Comment: @Ian Abbott i agree, but this just an idea

Comment: I think this is a straight and very good way. But actually, I'm learning the C preprocessor and wondering if there exists a recursive solution to get some of the Fibonacci sequence before running. Thank you for your answer~ @Silver

Answer (score 3):

Recursive macros are not allowed in C or in C++.

Macros — just a text replacement, not computation

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to perform recursive calculations by using the code pre-processor?

Comment: To some extend it is possible to have recursive macro in C. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540675/4989451

Comment: (a) Infinite recursion is not possible with macro replacement, but finite practical recursion is. (b) Macros substitute preprocessor tokens, not text. They can also stringize and concatenate. (c) The question asks about using preprocessor directives to evaluate the Fibonacci function, not just using macro replacement. So an answer must consider possibilities of using other directives, such as `#include`, which can be recursive.

Comment: (I see OP edited their question; it originally asked only about macros. So (c) was not an issue when this answer was written.)

Comment: And finally it is possible to implement Fibonacci function by preprocessor directives in C language (recursive includes and quite large file after preprocessing).

Comment: I'm so sorry, it's really my problem. I posted the question but then I discovered my inadequate expression, so I edited many times. I think I need more thinking before asking. Thank you very much for your help~ @RoiS

Comment: I think by reading your tips and some reference manual, I've gotten a better understanding of C macros. Thank you very much~ @EricPostpischil

Answer (score 2):

Using boost preprocessor's slots, and an iterative solution, with the macro `I` as input:

```
#ifndef INITIALIZE
#define INITIALIZE
# include <boost/preprocessor/slot.hpp>
# if I<=2
1
# else
#  define BOOST_PP_VALUE 2
#  include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)
#  define BOOST_PP_VALUE 1
#  include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(3)
#  define BOOST_PP_VALUE 1
#  include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(4)
#  include __FILE__
# endif
#else
#  define BOOST_PP_VALUE BOOST_PP_SLOT(1) + 1
#  include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)
#  define BOOST_PP_VALUE BOOST_PP_SLOT(3)
#  include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(2)
#  define BOOST_PP_VALUE BOOST_PP_SLOT(4)
#  include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(3)
#  define BOOST_PP_VALUE BOOST_PP_SLOT(2) + BOOST_PP_SLOT(3)
#  include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(4)
# if I==BOOST_PP_SLOT(1)
BOOST_PP_SLOT(4)
# else
#  include __FILE__
# endif
#endif
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c399d11dedc306ca