# Cartesian product of X-macro list with itself

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, x-macros

Suppose that, in C, I have an list of things specified using X-macros. For example,

```c
#define TYPES(X, ...) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, i, int) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, j, unsigned int) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, l, long) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, m, unsigned long)
```

If I add a second copy of that macro (call it `TYPES_`), it’s not hard to generate some code for each *pair* of things in the list; for example:

```c
#define TYPES_(X, ...) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, i, int) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, j, unsigned int) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, l, long) \
  X(__VA_ARGS__, m, unsigned long)
#define CAST(FROMCH, FROMTY, TOCH, TOTY) \
  TOTY FROMCH ## to ## TOCH (FROMTY x) { return (TOTY)x; }
TYPES_(TYPES, CAST)
```

However, if I use `TYPES` instead of the duplicate `TYPES_`, this code won’t work, because (I think?) the top-level expansion `TYPES` then contains an occurrence of `TYPES` itself, which is not permitted to expand further.

Is there a way to convince the C preprocessor to generate code for a cartesian product of a list with itself, like here, without specifying the list twice? It’s probably possible with [chaos/order-pp](https://github.com/rofl0r/order-pp)-style insanity that accomplishes a lot of expansions through [billion laughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack)-like hacks, but I’d prefer not to resort to that.

Comment: See [Can we have recursive macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540675/2402272).  The top-voted answer demonstrates a way to expand a macro an arbitrary (but fixed) number of times.  It looks like that would serve your purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `EXPAND` macro to perform delayed expansion. Rather clumsily:

```c
#define EXPAND(X) X
#define TYPES1() TYPES
#define TYPES2(...) TYPES1 EXPAND(())(__VA_ARGS__)
EXPAND(TYPES(TYPES2, CAST))
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mo5cjzbeh).