# Is there a way to call a macro on every argument in __VA_ARGS__?

Tags: c, macros, variadic-macros

for example:

```
#define M(x) do { x++; f(x); } while(0)

#define M_ALL(...) do { ??? } while(0)
```

Is there  a way to call `M` on each of the arguments of `M_ALL`?

such that doing this:

```
M_ALL(x, y, z)
```

would expand into:

```
do { 
    do { x++; f(x); } while(0); 
    do { y++; f(y); } while(0); 
    do { z++; f(z); } while(0); 
} while(0)
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540675/7582247) will help

Comment: Example: [`WI_FOREACH`](https://github.com/microsoft/wil/blob/087c5baa8bf56ee211c3b22b3510452b04713a5c/include/wil/common.h#L236)

Comment: You could take preprocessor from the boost C++ library. That material should actually work with a C compiler.

Answer (score 1):

What about using X macro ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_macro) . E.g:

```
#define LIST(DO) \
    DO(x) \
    DO(y) \
    DO(z)

#define M(x) do { x++; f(x); } while(0);

#define M_ALL(list) do { list( M ) } while(0) 

M_ALL(LIST);
```

Comment: This is probably the way to go, but you might want to use a different name than `x` for the macro parameter or it will get confusing since there is also an `x` in the X macro list.

Comment: Won't this only work for 3 args?

Comment: No, the list can be as long as it needs to be. If you want a list of 6 elements (e.g: e1 to e6) you can define a new list: `#define LIST2(DO) DO(e1) DO(e2) DO(e3) DO(e4) DO(e5) DO(e6)` and use it with `M_ALL(LIST2)`;

Comment: @MichaelWalshPedersen Yes but, I want every arg in the __VA_ARGS__ to have the macro applied to it. This only works with a limited number.

Comment: No, you cannot do unlimited list with __VA_ARGS__ . You can see how the WI_FOREACH macro (referred in the comments)  does it for a limit up to 100 elements.