Detect a parenthesized macro argument in C
I want a macro to detect whether the passed arg is surrounded by parentheses or not, and call a different macro if so.
e.g.
#define FOO(obj) BAR obj
#define BAR(...) func(__VA_ARGS__)
#define BAR

If I call this with FOO((1, 2, 3)) it'd expand to func(1, 2, 3). But if I call it with FOO(1) it should expand to 1
I know that macro overloading isn't a thing in C, but I'm wondering if there's another way to achieve this behavior from FOO. I looked into several macro tricks but couldn't figure out a way to do this.
I'm working on a macro library and need this exact behavior.

#define BAR(...) func(__VA_ARGS__) #define BAR is an error, it's a  duplicated definition. There can be only BAR, it's either a macro function or a macro.

What's the actual problem you are trying to solve here? FOO((1, 2, 3)) in the C language means execute the comma operator then pass one argument to the macro. The solution is not to use the extra parenthesis that changes the meaning of the code entirely.

@KamilCuk I know. I'm saying I want FOO to behave as if that were allowed, some kind of macro trick or something

This is, unfortunately, an XY problem.

@Lundin exactly, I want the macro to call a behave differently if the single arg is parenthesized

@Someprogrammerdude Like I said, I'm working on macro library where I want to provide this behavior

Why would you want that for? Changing the behavior of the C language makes your code dangerous, unreadable and unmaintainable.

@Lundin I'm working on an experimental C macro library.

For example lets say I'm a user of some library and I want to "mock" some function/macro to see how many times it is called. So I add some code deliberately using the comma operator for that: FOO((count++, actual argument)). Now if the skunky library somehow turns my code into 2 arguments, they break my valid and correct C code instead of it having it working as I, the C programmer who knows the C language but not your macro language, intended.

The thing about complexity is that it often makes the code too complex to be maintainable. Do you have an actual use-case for such a macro? What is that use-case? And if you don't have an actual use-case then I'd recommend you skip it until it's really needed. Don't add things that might be nice to have, sometime in the future, but doesn't really matter right now.

@Lundin: "execute the comma operator then pass one argument to the macro" No, that's not what it means - it means "pass (1,2,3) as the argument to the macro". Whether the commas get interpreted as the comma operator (as opposed to function argument delimiters) depends on how the macro uses its argument.

@psmears Fine, but it still means pass it along as one single pp token, not 3.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12540675/5196093 provides some control flow macros that should be useful.

@Someprogrammerdude Is it possible that the reason people view macros as complicated is because any time someone decides to work with them, everyone says "don't do that; they're too complicated" so they never get any practice?  Macros are a useful part of the language. If you want to limit yourself to a subset of the language, feel free, but if someone else wants to use the whole thing, don't try to talk them out of it.

@Ray I'm not saying that macros are not useful, in C they could be very useful. But adding complex features just in case they might be needed sometime in the future is just adding needless complexity without any reward.

@Someprogrammerdude Fair enough. I suppose I hear "macros considered harmful" often enough to have developed a kneejerk reaction against anything that sounds like it.  Your point is valid in the general case, but in this case, OP is writing a library, and to a certain extent, all library code is there "in case someone else might find it useful in the future".

@Lundin: It's more complicated than that: you can do #define SECOND(a,b,c) b and then #define FOO(x) SECOND x - and then FOO((1,2,3)) will expand to 2 - so, entirely within the preprocessor, you can break up the (1,2,3) into its constituents. (Of course, there's an entirely separate discussion to be had about whether you should do so ;-) ).

I have just written this. This can be simplified, it's just the first version that I got on godbolt that worked. Should be enough to get you started.
// if I call this with FOO((1, 2, 3)) it'd expand to func(1, 2, 3).
// But if I call it with FOO(1) it should expand to 1

#define ESCAPE2(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define ESCAPE(...)  ESCAPE2 __VA_ARGS__
#define COMMA(...)     ,
#define FIRST(T, ...)  T
// from https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/
#define ARG16(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, ...) _15
#define HAS_COMMA(...) ARG16(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
#define CONCAT(a, b)  a##b
#define XCONCAT(a, b)  CONCAT(a, b)
#define IF_1(a, b)  a
#define IF_0(a, b)  b
#define FOO(...)  \
        ESCAPE( \
            XCONCAT(IF_, HAS_COMMA(FIRST( COMMA __VA_ARGS__ () ))) \
            ((func __VA_ARGS__), (__VA_ARGS__)) \
        )

FOO((1,2,3)) // func (1,2,3)
FOO((1))  // func (1)
FOO(1)   // 1
FOO(1,2)   // 1,2

This looks nicer. After converting __VA_ARGS__ to a comma, it's just a matter of getting a proper arg position.
#define FOO_ESCAPE(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#define FOO_COMMA(...)     ,
#define FOO_FIRST(T, ...)  T
#define FOO_THIRD(_1,_2,_3,...)  \
        FOO_ESCAPE _3
#define FOO_XTHIRD(...)  \
        FOO_THIRD(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO(...)  \
        FOO_XTHIRD(__VA_OPT__(FOO_FIRST(FOO_COMMA __VA_ARGS__)), \
            (func __VA_ARGS__), (__VA_ARGS__) )
FOO((1,2,3))
FOO((1))
FOO()
FOO(1)
FOO(1,2)


this worked really well for me, Thanks! I did modify it slightly because my macro only accepts one arg not (...), which just means replacing __VA_ARGS__ with obj and removing __VA_OPT__.

#define FOO(...) DETAIL_FOO1( DETAIL_FOO0 __VA_ARGS__ ) )
#define DETAIL_FOO0(...) DETAIL_FOO0_ __VA_ARGS__
#define DETAIL_FOO1(...) DETAIL_FOO2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DETAIL_FOO2(...) DETAIL_FOO3_##__VA_ARGS__
#define DETAIL_FOO3_DETAIL_FOO0 (
#define DETAIL_FOO3_DETAIL_FOO0_ bar(

FOO(1) // (1)
FOO((1,2,3)) // bar(1,2,3)

In this case FOO(1) expands to (1) and not 1, but this is probably more desirable.
Turns out this incorrectly accepts FOO((1,2)3), expanding it to bar(1,2 3). With additional macro gymnastics you can reject that:
#define FOO(...) DETAIL_FOO1( DETAIL_FOOA(__VA_ARGS__) ) )
#define DETAIL_FOOA(...) DETAIL_FOO0 __VA_ARGS__ )
#define DETAIL_FOO0(...) DETAIL_FOO0_ __VA_ARGS__ REQUIRE_EMPTY(
#define DETAIL_FOO1(...) DETAIL_FOO2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DETAIL_FOO2(...) DETAIL_FOO3_##__VA_ARGS__
#define DETAIL_FOO3_DETAIL_FOO0 ( IDENTITY(
#define DETAIL_FOO3_DETAIL_FOO0_ bar(
#define REQUIRE_EMPTY()
#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__

