Why does my variadic macro throw an error when nothing is passed?
Context
I'm trying to create a C program that takes multiple integers as input via the print(...) macro, without needing to pass the length of arguments manually from the main function. To achieve this, I implemented a macro to automatically determine the number of arguments passed and then print them.
Here’s the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void function_for_printing(int len, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, len);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            int temp = va_arg(args, int);
            printf("%d ", temp);
        }
        va_end(args);
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        va_end(args);
        printf("\nNothing passed\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

#define print(...) ({\
    int array[]= {__VA_ARGS__};\
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);\
    if(size==0)\
    {\
        function_for_printing(0);\
    }\
    else if (size!=0)\
    {\
        function_for_printing(size, __VA_ARGS__);\
    }\
})

int main()
{
    print(1, 2, 4); // works fine
    print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7); // works fine
    print(); // throws an error

    return 0;
}

My objective:
I want the print(...) macro to:

Automatically determine the number of arguments passed (without explicitly passing the size).
Print the arguments using function_for_printing(int, ...).
If no arguments are passed, the macro should print "Nothing passed" without throwing an error.

Issue:
When no arguments are passed to print(), the program throws an error during compilation. I expected the program to handle an empty input by printing "Nothing passed". I understand that __VA_ARGS__ can cause problems when no arguments are passed.
What I tried:

I typecasted __VA_ARGS__ into an int[].
I calculated the length using sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]).
Based on the length, I either pass the arguments to function_for_printing() or call it with 0 if the length is zero.
When the length is zero, I wanted it to handle the case gracefully, but the macro doesn’t seem to support empty __VA_ARGS__ as expected.

Question:
How can I modify my code or macro to handle cases where no arguments are passed to print(...) without causing errors?
Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

What error? Empty arrays are not generally supported in C. Might be supported as an extension.

When you pass no arguments, you end up with function_for_printing(size, ). Even though the code doesn't get executed, it still needs to be valid.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/79070556/589924

What ikegami probably meant to say with the link is this: rewrite function_for_printing(size, __VA_ARGS__) into function_for_printing(size, ##__VA_ARGS__).

And what part of the language spec do you say defines the meaning of that, @CarlHR?

@JohnBollinger My comment simply implies a solution from a post I record to have seen some time ago. I forgot to link it on my comment. I do not know the specifics surrounding the "language specs", as I'm not the one who came up with this solution. It's this post entirely if you're curious.

@CarlHR, my comment was largely rhetorical.  The point is that no version of standard C defines the effect of the token-pasting operator in a way that makes your suggestion effective for solving the OP's problem.  GNU C provides such behavior as an extension, but that's no longer standard C.  There are definitely compilers that do not implement that extension.

Standard C does not provide a solution, first and foremost because it does not define behavior for an invocation of a variadic macro that does not include at least one variable argument.  Your most portable alternative is to just specify that at least one argument must be passed to your print() macro.  If you like, you can supplement it with another (non-variadic) macro for the zero-arg special case.  Unless you're working deep macro voodoo (not recommended) you should know which alternative you need in every situation.

@JohnBollinger C23 does have __VA_OPT__ which does make the GNU C extension ##__VA_ARGS__ obsolete. I posted an answer with such a solution.

Acknowledged, @Lundin, except there is no C23, and as far as I am aware, standard C is still C17.  There might not even end up being a C24, but I'm holding out hope that C2X will finally land in 2025.

@JohnBollinger You can watch the wheels of bureaucracy turn (ever so slowly) live here: ISO/IEC 9899. C23 went into the publication phase at 27/9 and that phase might take up to 7 weeks. If that can be trusted, it should be published mid November. The technical work was done in summer 2022... It takes ISO 1.5 years to publish a pdf...


Why does my variadic macro throw an error when nothing is passed?

Because in current ISO C ("C17"), the line int array[]= {__VA_ARGS__}; would get pre-processed into this:
int array[]= {};

And that's invalid C for now. Upcoming C23 will actually allow the {} syntax with the same meaning as {0}. However, you will still not be able to write array[] = {} with the size unspecified, because this syntax means "give me an array size equivalent to the number of initializers I typed" and then if you type no initializers, that's nonsensical code.
As it turns out, you shouldn't be declaring an array in the first place - a compound literal would be a better solution inside a macro.
Standard C23 will also have a new feature __VA_OPT__ which allows conditional expansion of variadic macros and only expand the stuff within __VA_OPT__(stuff) in case there were arguments passed.
So C23 would solve all problems, whereas C17 or older will have to rely on non-portable GNU extensions, such as the non-standard GNU solution ##__VA_ARGS__ - don't use that.
The only downside of __VA_OPT__ is that it leads to some seriously hard to read macros.

Possible solution
Lets say we either want to call the function print if there are no arguments or otherwise print_stuff if there are arguments. Example:
#define print(...) print ## __VA_OPT__(_stuff) (PRINT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))

Here from the macro print we either call a function print in case there were no arguments or otherwise call print_stuff. If there were no arguments then __VA_OPT__ expands to a "do nothing" placeholder token, otherwise it expands to stuff. Either can be used with token concatenation ## to create the function name. So print ## __VA_OPT__(_stuff) either expands to print or print_stuff.
The part inside the parenthesis (PRINT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) is the function call with potential arguments. To ease readability I made some helper macros to hide some of the messy code. It goes:
#define COUNT_ARGS(...) ( sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int) )
#define PRINT_ARGS(...) __VA_OPT__((const int[]){__VA_ARGS__}, COUNT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))

As in, if there were no arguments passed to PRINT_ARGS then __VA_OPT__ will dissolve into nothing and that's suitable for calling a function with parameter (void). Otherwise, we create a compound literal that's passed to the function along with a size. COUNT_ARGS is used for determining the size, again by using a compound literal.
So it's quite evil code to read, but also with some serious advantages:

100% standard ISO C23 with no GNU crap extensions.
Increased type safety, same as any int array initialization, which is a whole lot safer than using va_list, which has non-existent type safety.
Removes the need to use the notoriously dangerous stdarg.h library, which simply shouldn't be used in well-designed programs.
The called functions turn much more readable.

Full code:
#include <stdio.h>

static void print (void)
{
  puts("Nothing passed");
}

static void print_stuff (const int* arr, size_t size)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  puts("");
}

#define COUNT_ARGS(...) ( sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int) )
#define PRINT_ARGS(...) __VA_OPT__((const int[]){__VA_ARGS__}, COUNT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))
#define print(...) print ## __VA_OPT__(_stuff) (PRINT_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))
    
int main (void)
{
  print();
  print(1,2,3);
  print(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
}

Output:
Nothing passed
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 


With the 2 helper macros (from other stackoverflow answers):
#define is_empty(dummy, ...) ( sizeof( (char[]){#__VA_ARGS__} ) == 1 )
#define       NUMARGS(...)  (sizeof((int[]){0, ##__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int)-1)

the changed macro does what you want:
#define print(...) do{\
    if (is_empty(__VA_ARGS__)) \
        function_for_printing(0);\
    else\
        function_for_printing( NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__), ##__VA_ARGS__ );\
}while(0)

The important part is the use of ## before possibly empty __VA_ARGS__.
Running example: https://godbolt.org/z/PMvsMY6r8
Interestingly, the following macro also works:
#define print(...) function_for_printing( NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__), ##__VA_ARGS__ )

So, the new (quite short) example is here: https://godbolt.org/z/xh7Ga8fdr

You are compiling it wrong. For strict ISO C you can't just type -pedantic, you have to also specify which C standard to use or else you are asking for "pedantic non-standard GNU C". And the code you posted here isn't standard C. Actually gcc seems plain broken here, use clang and watch the compiler errors.
